# different templates and objects in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement a feed with ng-repeat. The feed items have to be sorted by recency. However, I can't possibly use the same template for each item, because the events and behaviors are different. Would using ng-if to render the feed events like this make sense?

```
<ul ng-controller="FeedController as FeedCtrl">
 <li ng-repeat="feedItem in FeedCtrl.feedFactory.feedItems | orderBy '-date_created'">
    <div feed-comment-liked ng-if="feedItem.type == 'comment_liked'" item-info ="feedItem">
    <div feed-comment-reply ng-if="feedItem.type == 'comment_reply'" item-info ="feedItem">
    <div feed-friend-request ng-if="feedItem.type == 'friend-request'" item-info ="feedItem">
 </li>
</ul>
```

This would of course necessitate a number of directives called feedCommentLiked, feedCommentReply, and feedFriendRequest, each with their own template, and getting their data through an item-info binding.

I think this is ok, but I'm hoping others have been down this road. The most obvious constraint in why I don't include multiple ng-repeat lists is that they need to be ordered by the same "date_created" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thin directive approach so you would have one directive.

```
<ul ng-controller="FeedController as FeedCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="feedItem in FeedCtrl.feedFactory.feedItems | orderBy '-date_created'">
<div thin-directive="{{myConfig[feedItem.type]}}" item-info ="feedItem">
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.myConfig = {
   comment_liked: 'template url here',
   comment_reply: 'template url here',
   friend-request: 'template url here',
}

-----

.directive('thinDirective', function($compile,$templateRequest) {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: false, 
  compile: function(element, attrs) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $templateRequest(attrs.thinDirective).then(function(html){
      var template = angular.element(html);
      element.append(template);
      $compile(template)(scope);
    });
  }
}

};
```

or you can use ng-include instead of thin directive but it will create N subscopes. Your call

```
<ul ng-controller="FeedController as FeedCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="feedItem in FeedCtrl.feedFactory.feedItems | orderBy '-date_created'">
<div ng-include="myConfig[feedItem.type]" item-info ="feedItem">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Aside from lacking the ng-if statements in the innerHtml of the ng-repeated element, I guess I see that you could centralize the issue in one file. But that's about it. Might be a good approach.

Comment: But I can't shake the feeling that this workaround isn't leveraging the framework properly :-/

Comment: It's not a workaround to be honest in that case you are not performing 3xN comparisons ( if statements ) regarding ng-repeat. You are just taking values from the map and applying template. More over you are also not creating subscopes which you would with use of ng-include. You can use ng-include if you would like to - but in that case you will create N subscopes. So native solution to angular would be usage of ng-include and map myConfig above - but this solution ( with thin directive ) has better performance. I've updated my answer with ng-include solution

Comment: wouldn't you be rendering every template type for each feed item regardless of whether or not it was applicable? and the ng-if can be a one-time binding if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Not a problem, if it is not applicable then you will return nil value so nothing will be rendered ( you can extend this solution if you like for example to default template or wrap it in a function if you like ). If my answer is correct can we mark it as an accepted one? Thanks.